# What is the best position for mudguard in cycle

Tags: fenders, mud

I have a MTB/Hybrid which I use for exercising and leisure purpose. It have installed MTB style mudguards. But when I get out with these my back is full of mud/water drops.

So what is the best position for these style of mudguards? Specially rear mudguard. I have attached the photo of my bike which shows the position of my mudguard. Can changing these position will improve the effectiveness?

[image: Position of mudguard on my bike]

Comment: If you look at the duplicate-tagged question, you'll see a diagram that explains how fender angle affects splatter. Basically, you'll want to get the fender to be as low and close to the wheel as possible, but also oriented to the aft of the bike. Your fender is too short to give you comprehensive coverage.

Comment: @RoboKaren until I saw your answer I wasn't going to agree with the close vote but that's a better answer to this question than the one I wrote (before you pointed out the dupe)

Answer (score 4):

With a hardtail like that you can fit a full rear mudguard that covers much more of the tyre, especially towards the back of the wheel, and covers it more closely With what you've got you're never going to keep your back from getting splashed. You can experiment with the angle and height to see if you can get a little better, but I doubt it's worth it. Those mudguards will keep the worst of the mud off your (lower) back but that's about all - fine drops of water  get everywhere and soon soak you.